# Selenium Python - Product array page, how do dynamically click a product

Tags: python, selenium

saksoff5th.com is the site URL that i am using. I search via text "Belts" on the home page and then click Men link. This takes me to the product array page of men's belt. I want to click the 2nd product on the array, but i am getting error.

The code i am using is. Here in i am trying to put all of those in a list and then click the second product on the page.

```
elemprodcl = browser.find_element_by_id('search-result-items')
Listprdcl= elemprodcl.find_elements_by_class_name('grid-tile')
elemprodcl2 = Listprdcl[1].find_element_by_class_name('product-tile')
elemprodcl3 = elemprodcl2.find_element_by_class_name('product-image')
elemprodcl4 = elemprodcl3.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()
```

Error received as :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Off5th_Guest_Checkout", line 39, in <module>
    elemprodcl4 = elemprodcl3.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 59, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 369, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you were nearly there. You were trying to click the `a` Web element, where as you should try to click the `img`.

So continuing from where you left off :

```
elemprodcl4 = elemprodcl3.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
elemprodcl4.find_element_by_tag_name('img').click()
```

or simply by using a single CSS selector:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.search-result-items li:nth-child(2) div > div > a').click()
```

Explanation of the css selector syntax-

- `.search-result-items` is the class name as the text is preceded by a
  dot.
- `li` is the descendant(child) of the above class. and the `nth-child`
  indicates which child from the list (array) of children do we want to
  select
- Similar for `div` and `a`, they are children of the preceding
  selector mentioned

Comment: Thanks Amey, the clicking of image did the job. However, i would like to try via the CSS selector too. I am not too clear how to use it. Can you please explain the syntax and how we use it? Will Really appreciate it.